# pthread code and How to reach this output

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to Interpret how to reach this output for at least 5 different outputs.
And Modify the program to fix this problem.How Can I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *threadFunc(void *pArg)
 { 
 int *p = (int*)pArg;
 int myNum = *p;
 printf("Thread number %d\n", myNum);
 return 0;
}
int main(void) 
{
 int i;
 pthread_t tid [NUM_THREADS];
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) 
{
 pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, threadFunc, &i);
}
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
 { 
 pthread_join(tid [i], NULL);
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear, and the code is unreadable. Kindly edit the question to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread function receives pointer to `int`. Memory it points to is shared between threads, so while thread function reads value of `i` it is changed by main thread. This is race condition.
You can fix it by storing individual `i` values for each thread:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *threadFunc(void *pArg)
{ 
    int *p = (int*)pArg;
    int myNum = *p;
    printf("Thread number %d\n", myNum);
    return NULL;    // thread function returns a pointer
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
    int data[NUM_THREADS];
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) 
    {
        data[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, threadFunc, data+i); // `data+i` is equivalent to `&data[i]`
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    { 
        pthread_join(tid [i], NULL);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Another option is to pass an integer as a pointer value. It doesn't require storage for each thread but may cause truncating problems because of `int`<->`intptr_t` conversion.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <inttypes.h>   // for intptr_t
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{ 
    int myNum = (intptr_t)arg;
    printf("Thread number %d\n", myNum);
    return NULL;    // thread function returns a pointer
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, threadFunc, (void *)(intptr_t)i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    { 
        pthread_join(tid [i], NULL);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```